# Не сохраняются данные в БД

Tags: sql, delphi, sql-server

Клиентское приложение написано на Delphi с использованием библиотек `DevExpress` `vcl`, подключаюсь к `MS SQL` серверу.
Подключаюсь к БД в связке `DataSourse` `ADOQuery`.

Столкнулся с такого рода проблемой:

Изменяю значение поля :

```
procedure TForm24.cxButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
DM.tviezdi.edit;
Dm.Tviezdi.FieldByName('Выезд').AsString  := 'Да';
DM.Tviezdi.post;
showmessage ('Аварком '+cxDBLookupComboBox3.Text+' назначен')
end;
```

Оно вроде изменяется и отображается в гриде (Изменен аварком на Яковлева)
[link text](http://i57.fastpic.ru/big/2013/1121/45/f339b23059f41f98c80da59c9b074a45.png)

Запускаю фильтр

```
procedure TForm13.cxButton5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
dm.Tviezdi.Active := false;
dm.Tviezdi.SQL.clear;
Dm.Tviezdi.SQL.Add('set language Russian  set dateformat dmy ');
// Dm.Tviezdi.SQL.Add('select *');
  Dm.Tviezdi.SQL.Add('select ');
  Dm.Tviezdi.SQL.Add('[dbo].[Дата последнего изменения состояния дела]([dbo].[БД].[№ Заявки]) [Дата последнего изменения состояния дела],');
  Dm.Tviezdi.SQL.Add('[dbo].[Просрочка состояния дела]([dbo].[БД].[№ Заявки])[Просрочено],');
  Dm.Tviezdi.SQL.Add('[dbo].[БД].[№ Заявки] idLoss,');
  Dm.Tviezdi.SQL.Add('*');
  Dm.Tviezdi.SQL.Add('FROM  [dbo].[БД]');
  Dm.Tviezdi.SQL.Add('LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Фото инфо]');
  Dm.Tviezdi.SQL.Add('ON [dbo].[Фото инфо].[№ заявки] = [dbo].[БД].[№ Заявки]');
  DM.Tviezdi.SQL.Add('WHERE 1=1');
  DM.Tviezdi.SQL.Add('-- find');
  Dm.Tviezdi.SQL.Add('AND([Дата осмотра]  >= '+#39+cxDateEdit1.Text+#39')');
Dm.Tviezdi.SQL.Add('and ([Дата осмотра]  <= '+#39+cxDateEdit2.Text+#39')');
Dm.Tviezdi.SQL.Add('Order By [№ Заявки] Desc');
Dm.Tviezdi.ExecSQL;
dm.Tviezdi.Active := true;
end;
```

[link text](http://i59.fastpic.ru/big/2013/1121/0b/37e02a058616d2f36b8eec7e46c74b0b.png)

И вижу старые данные (аварком стал Уваров как и был), то есть поле записалось в грид, а в БД нет. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Однако, если фильтр не запускать, то данные почему-то сохраняются, а после применения фильтра поменять уже ничего не получается.

Comment: жесть какая. grid сам умеет прекрасно фильтровать, а уж cxGrid тем более. зачем вам вообще нужен sql-запрос?

Comment: Может быть... , фильтр нужен для того , чтобы отобразить все данные удовлетворяющие условиям фильтра из БД, а не только те , которые сейчас расположены в cxGrid. Но вопрос не в этом)
Как я понимаю, проблема возникает при dm.Tviezdi.Active := false; и dm.Tviezdi.Active := true; , отключения и подключения снова к базе, но почему он не сохраняет?

Comment: При работе с Sql запросами есть два варианта , в одном случае он создает копию таблицы и она доступна только для просмотра, во втором случае никакой таблицы не создается и данные доступны для редактирования , видимо необходимо писать запрос с update, с компонентами BDE был компонент SqlUpdate , его настроил и проблема решена , а как с компонентами ADO реализовать?

Comment: Возможно там есть некая функция: **СУБД.post;** которая и делает занесение всех изменений в базу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась довольно просто. Дописываем строки:

```
DM.tviezdi.LockType:= ltBatchOptimistic
```

или

```
DM.tviezdi.LockType:= ltOptimistic
```

Далее добавил кнопку в окне, где Grid ,и на нее дописал:

```
DM.Tviezdi.UpdateBatch(arAll);
```

Все заработало.   [Здесь](http://da-soft.com/forums/freedac-osnovnoj-russkij/) есть по подробней.